# $T$ is normal iff $T^*=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have learned the spectral theorem for a linear operator $T$ on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$ over a field $F$, and now I'm attempting to get some corollaries to this theorem. For this poster, I would like to ask for some details of the following corollary.

> Let $F=\mathbb C$. $T$ is normal iff $T^*=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g$.

For the "only if" part, we begin by applying the spectral theorem to obtain the decomposition $T=\lambda_1 T_1+\ldots+\lambda_k T_k$, where $\lambda_i$'s are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$ and each $T_i$ is the orthogonal projection on the corresponding eigenspace. Next, we take the adjoints of both sides of the decomposition and obtain $T^*=\overline{\lambda_1}T_1+\ldots+\overline{\lambda_k}T_k$. Note that, in this step, we have used the fact that any orthogonal projection is self-adjoint. **Here** comes the problem. I don't know how to use the Lagrange interpolation formula to get a polynomial $g$ such that $g(\lambda_i)=\overline{\lambda_i}$ for all $i$. The existence of $g$ is critical in completing the proof. Please give me some advice. Many Thanks.

Comment: The Lagrange interpolating formula shows how to find a polynomial so that $f(x_k) = y_k$ for any given $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n$ where the $x_i$s are distinct.  So you just set $x_k = \lambda_k$ and $y_k = \bar\lambda_k$.  Where is the difficulty?

Comment: You don't *need* to use Lagrange interpolation formula if you are not comfortable with it.  For example, you could write down the $k$ linear equations for the coefficients of the degree $\leq k-1$ polynomial and note the Vandemonde matrix there.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot the meaning of the Lagrange interpolation formula. After reviewing the material, I'm now OK with the argument. Thank you all.